# Access a URL Parameter in a Route Prefix from Middleware

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5, laravel-request

I am struggling to access a route prefix parameter from my middleware.

Given this URL: `http://www.example.com/api/v1/campaign/40/status`, and the following route:

```
Route::group( [
    'prefix' => 'api/v1'
], function()
{
    Route::group( [
        'prefix' => 'campaign/{campaign}',
        'where' => [ 'campaign' => '[0-9]+' ],
        'middleware' => [
            'inject_campaign'
        ]
    ], function()
    {
        Route::get( 'status', 'CampaignController@getStatus' );
    } );
} );
```

How do I access the campaign parameter (40 in the example URL) from my inject_campaign middleware? I have the middleware running fine but cannot work out how to access the parameter.

Calling `$request->segments()` in my middleware gives me the parts of the route but this seems a fragile way of accessing the data. What if the route changes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it using shorter syntax

You can use:

```
echo $request->route()->campaign;
```

or even shorter:

```
echo $request->campaign;
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

`$request->route()->getParameter('campaign')`